# Change font family to formattable in R

Tags: html, r, kable, formattable

Does anyone know how to change the font family when using formattable when producing an image to render in pdf?

I currently have the following table given that code.

```
library("htmltools")
library("webshot")  
library(formattable)
DF <- data.frame(Ticker=c("", "", "", "IBM", "AAPL", "MSFT"),
                 Name=c("Dow Jones", "S&P 500", "Technology", 
                        "IBM", "Apple", "Microsoft"),
                 Value=accounting(c(15988.08, 1880.33, 50, 
                                    130.00, 97.05, 50.99)),
                 Change=percent(c(-0.0239, -0.0216, 0.021, 
                                  -0.0219, -0.0248, -0.0399)))

unit.scale = function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
export_formattable <- function(f, file, width = "100%", height = NULL, 
                               background = "white", delay = 0.2)
    {
      w <- as.htmlwidget(f, width = width, height = height)
      path <- html_print(w, background = background, viewer = NULL)
      url <- paste0("file:///", gsub("\\\\", "/", normalizePath(path)))
      webshot(url,
              file = file,
              selector = ".formattable_widget",
              delay = delay)
    }
FT <- formattable(DF, list(
  Name=formatter("span", 
                 style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology", style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)), #NOT APPLIED when we output to PNG with the function!
  #Value = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  Value = color_bar("orange" , fun = unit.scale
                    ),
  Change = formatter("span", 
                     style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green"), "font.size" = "18px"), 
                     x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x)
                     )),
  table.attr = 'style="font-size: 18px;";\"')

FT
export_formattable(FT,"FT.png")
```

[image]
However, I want to change the whole font family of the table to Calibri, I tried many different things to no avail, please help!

Comment: Also, when outputing this to a rmarkdown pdf the bold text is just ignored! nothing is printed in bold please help

Comment: If you reproduce my example you will find out that indeed the text formatting is modified when i use my export function, I do really need Calibri font!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the font by adding `font-family: Calibri` to `table.attr`.

**Code**

```
FT <- formattable(DF, list(
  Name=formatter("span", 
                 style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology", style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)), #NOT APPLIED when we output to PNG with the function!
  #Value = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  Value = color_bar("orange" , fun = unit.scale
  ),
  Change = formatter("span", 
                     style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green"), "font.size" = "18px"), 
                     x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x)
  )),
  table.attr = 'style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Calibri";\"')

FT
export_formattable(FT,"FT.png")
```

**Output**
[image]